# Does OpenCL on an APU capable of using the whole memory?

Tags: c, opencl, pyopencl

Is it possible to build a machine with something like 32GB of RAM, and use about ~28GB with OpenCL?

My current APU is an Athlon 5350, with a "global memory size" reported of 2142658560. I played a little with pyopencl with the CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, but I didn't find a way for doing that.

Is that possible at all?
May be with some new generation APU, like Ryzen Vega?

NOTE: I'm a non-professional and newbie, I didn't spend a hour yet studing OpenCL because before investing money and time on this, I want to know if it's possible at all... so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a 32GB computer and to devote ~28GB of it's RAM to any program.  When you are writing an OpenCL program, all management of memory spaces (on-chip and off-chip) must be done manually.  I do not think you can run an OpenCL kernel that seems to directly accessing RAM, but even if you could, that would not be particularly worth thinking about because the power of OpenCL is in fine-grained management of RAM, L2, and L1 - not in allowing programmers to consider their program as operating against just RAM.

Take some time, dive deep into memory management, and gain a very firm grasp of your computer's several memory spaces of varying sizes, connection speeds, and connection bandwidths.

You seem to be thinking about buying a huge amount of RAM to solve your problem.  Hopefully you can find a better way to architect your solution - one that does not involve buying 128GB of RAM.

That said, some programs are inherently hard to parallelize.  For these programs you might just want to buy a ton of RAM (and maybe even skip OpenCL entirely and run it on the CPU)

Comment: The problem is that even with a GPU running in the speed of light, the program would be slow as hell if I divide it into chunks, because each step of the program will need the results of the previous step, so even if I use the fastest SSD i'll be copying 10GB to the GPU, then writing results to the SSD, then loading another 10GB.... and this bottleneck would hide any gains from using a GPU.

Comment: @WillianBritto yes, is possible that buying a huge amount RAM is the best choice for your situation